# Get the value which I set before

Tags: java, class, setter, getter

I have a little problem with my program, that includes 2 classes. 
I want to use the Text of my jTextField1 at this moment when the user clicks on the New-button of my program. Than I want to use this value in the second class to write a simple file.

This is the code of Class1:

```
public class Class1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {     
    Class2 network = new Class2(); 

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        network.setID(jTextField1.getText());
        Class2.New();
    }
}
```

And Class 2:

```
public class Class2 {    
    String tempID = "";
    public void setID(String ID){
        ID = tempID;
    }
    public static void New(){
        Class1 ID = new Class1();
        /* Here i want to save the value in a string */
        String f = string + ".dat";
        try{        
            FileOutputStream outx = new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\NetworkAdmin\\data\\" + f);
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(outx);
            out.println("test");
            out.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

I hope it's enough ;) thanks for the help

Comment: You can pass the text as parameter to New.

Comment: code is missing from CLass1

Comment: can you get it compilable? Im still not sure exactly what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

You have a new value to save for each call of `Neu`.  Stuff like this is *why* you use classes.

```
Neu item = new Neu();
String item = item.getValue();
```

Unless there is some really compelling reason to use `static`, avoid it.  It only permits poor coding practices to slip into your object-oriented code.

Answer (score 0):

You cant access a non-static field inside a static method. So, either make both the method and the field static or non-static. Also in setID for class2 you are setting ID = tempID, it should be tempID = ID.

This is the code of Class1:

```
public class Class1 extends javax.swing.JFrame {     
    Class2 network = new Class2(); 

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        network.setID(jTextField1.getText());
        network.New();
    }
}
```

And Class 2:

```
public class Class2 {    
    String tempID = "";
    public void setID(String ID){
        tempID = ID;
    }
    public void New(){
        Class1 ID = new Class1();
        /* Here i want to save the value in a string */
        //String f = string + ".dat";
        String f = tempID + ".dat"; // this should work - use tempID which you set before
        try{        
            FileOutputStream outx = new FileOutputStream("C:\\temp\\NetworkAdmin\\data\\" + f);
            PrintStream out = new PrintStream(outx);
            out.println("test");
            out.close();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.err.println(e.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

you have an instance variable in Class2, but you are not setting it. i guess what you really mean to do instead of

```
public void setID(String ID){
    ID = tempID;
}
```

change to

```
public void setID(String ID){
    tempID = ID;
}
```

and then use

```
String f = tempID + ".dat";
```

NOTE: then you would either have to declare tempID as static, or change your method to non static and call using the object i.e. network

Comment: Do you think this answer really solves the problem ?

Comment: @Plexus i believe so, but i may be wrong. what do you think would be the problem with this solution?